# Blank and correct result showing in log/console for single variable

Tags: java, regex

I have a curious situation I am not able to nail down... I have a number I get from a string with regex. On returning this number in the console through Log.e() it gives me a blank result and a result with the correct number (console results):

```
11-08 21:06:36.381: E/SITEID(16544): 
11-08 21:06:36.381: E/SITEID(16544): 852
11-08 21:06:36.382: E/SITEID(16544): 
11-08 21:06:36.382: E/SITEID(16544): 859
11-08 21:06:36.383: E/SITEID(16544): 
11-08 21:06:36.383: E/SITEID(16544): 868
11-08 21:06:36.384: E/SITEID(16544): 
11-08 21:06:36.384: E/SITEID(16544): 872
11-08 21:06:36.385: E/SITEID(16544): 
11-08 21:06:36.385: E/SITEID(16544): 875
```

Here is an example string:

```
String siteNumber = "<a href="http://www.wcc.nrcs.usda.gov/nwcc/site?sitenum=875">Site Info</a>";
```

Here is my regex:

```
String siteid = siteNumber.replaceAll(".*\\=|\\\".*","");
```

I am running this through a check for null and stripping it of any extra spaces:

```
siteid.replaceAll("\\s", "");

if (siteid != null && !siteid.isEmpty()) {}
```

Where is this extra result coming from? Why is it empty and why isn't my replace and null check picking it up?

Comment: Strange... I sanitized the data just out of the array before I assigned it to variables and it worked... splitData[j].replaceAll("\\W", ""); Any ideas why this wasn't working after the array?

Answer (score 0):

Without having a little more information, it's hard to tell what you're issue is. Just looking at the code, one possibility would be whitespace. So if you trimmed the `siteid` variable before the if statement it might solve your problem. If you have an example of the input string that causes the problem, it'd be a lot easier to tell you why.

I think a more reliable solution would be to do a regex match on the string instead of doing a replace all.

Like so:

```
String siteNumber = "<a href=\"http://www.wcc.nrcs.usda.gov/nwcc/site?sitenum=852\">Site Info</a>";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("sitenum=(\\d+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(siteNumber);
if (matcher.find()) {
    String siteId = matcher.group(1);
    System.out.println(siteId);
}
```

This has the benefit of only matching if the sitenum parameter is in the URL and it's set to a valid integer. This would solve the problem you're having.